# mutex / what is the mutex data being locked?

Tags: c++, mutex

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "errors.h"


    typedef struct alarm_tag {
struct alarm_tag    *link;
int                 seconds;
time_t              time;   /* seconds from EPOCH */
char                message[64];
    } alarm_t;

    pthread_mutex_t alarm_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
alarm_t *alarm_list = NULL;


void *alarm_thread (void *arg)
{
alarm_t *alarm;
int sleep_time;
time_t now;
int status;


while (1) {
    status = pthread_mutex_lock (&alarm_mutex);
    if (status != 0)
        err_abort (status, "Lock mutex");
    alarm = alarm_list;

    /*
     * If the alarm list is empty, wait for one second. This
     * allows the main thread to run, and read another
     * command. If the list is not empty, remove the first
     * item. Compute the number of seconds to wait -- if the
     * result is less than 0 (the time has passed), then set
     * the sleep_time to 0.
     */
    if (alarm == NULL)
        sleep_time = 1;
    else {
        alarm_list = alarm->link;
        now = time (NULL);
        if (alarm->time <= now)
            sleep_time = 0;
        else
            sleep_time = alarm->time - now;
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf ("[waiting: %d(%d)\"%s\"]\n", alarm->time,
            sleep_time, alarm->message);
#endif
        }

    /*
     * Unlock the mutex before waiting, so that the main
     * thread can lock it to insert a new alarm request. If
     * the sleep_time is 0, then call sched_yield, giving
     * the main thread a chance to run if it has been
     * readied by user input, without delaying the message
     * if there's no input.
     */
    status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&alarm_mutex);
    if (status != 0)
        err_abort (status, "Unlock mutex");
    if (sleep_time > 0)
        sleep (sleep_time);
    else
        sched_yield ();

    /*
     * If a timer expired, print the message and free the
     * structure.
     */
    if (alarm != NULL) {
        printf ("(%d) %s\n", alarm->seconds, alarm->message);
        free (alarm);
    }
}
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int status;
    char line[128];
    alarm_t *alarm, **last, *next;
    pthread_t thread;

status = pthread_create (
    &thread, NULL, alarm_thread, NULL);
if (status != 0)
    err_abort (status, "Create alarm thread");
while (1) {
    printf ("alarm> ");
    if (fgets (line, sizeof (line), stdin) == NULL) exit (0);
    if (strlen (line) <= 1) continue;
    alarm = (alarm_t*)malloc (sizeof (alarm_t));
    if (alarm == NULL)
        errno_abort ("Allocate alarm");

    /*
     * Parse input line into seconds (%d) and a message
     * (%64[^\n]), consisting of up to 64 characters
     * separated from the seconds by whitespace.
     */
    if (sscanf (line, "%d %64[^\n]", 
        &alarm->seconds, alarm->message) < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Bad command\n");
        free (alarm);
    } else {
        status = pthread_mutex_lock (&alarm_mutex);
        if (status != 0)
            err_abort (status, "Lock mutex");
        alarm->time = time (NULL) + alarm->seconds;

        /*
         * Insert the new alarm into the list of alarms,
         * sorted by expiration time.
         */
        last = &alarm_list;
        next = *last;
        while (next != NULL) {
            if (next->time >= alarm->time) {
                alarm->link = next;
                *last = alarm;
                break;
            }
            last = &next->link;
            next = next->link;
        }
        /*
         * If we reached the end of the list, insert the new
         * alarm there. ("next" is NULL, and "last" points
         * to the link field of the last item, or to the
         * list header).
         */
        if (next == NULL) {
            *last = alarm;
            alarm->link = NULL;
        }
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf ("[list: ");
        for (next = alarm_list; next != NULL; next = next->link)
            printf ("%d(%d)[\"%s\"] ", next->time,
                next->time - time (NULL), next->message);
        printf ("]\n");
#endif
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&alarm_mutex);
        if (status != 0)
            err_abort (status, "Unlock mutex");
    }
}
    }
```

Hi this is my code, can anyone tell me because the mutex is not declared in the struct. So when the mutex locks and unlocks, what data is actually being changed can someone enlighten me?

Comment: "Hi this is my code, can anyone tell me what does it do?" - Are you for real?

Comment: as in its from my lecture slides, im just wondering when you lock the mutex, and the thread edits data, where is this set of data that is being protected by the mutex?

Comment: So it's not your code. Why don't you ask the person who wrote it?

Answer (score 1):

> where is this set of data that is being protected by the mutex?

The mutex object is `alarm_mutex`. The data "protected" by it doesn't have to be explicitely mentioned in the code; as in, there doesn't need to be a semantic connection. A mutex is a low-level threading primitive and as such the user needs to build his own logic around that. In your case, that one place in memory is used to block other parts of your code, those accessing actual data, from interfering.

Think about it this way: `std::atomic<int> x;` expresses the atomicity of operations on it. `int x; mutex m;` requires every piece of the code accessing `x` to properly look at `m` to ensure the correctness of the program. This low-level acess is what we're looking at in your example.

Comment: so would it be correct to say, from the code lock mutex to the unlocking of mutex, all the data there is being processed there cannot be interfered with?

Comment: @RaphaelSeize absolutely not. It can easily be 'interfered with' by another thread that does not bother to acquire the mutex first.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_mutex_t alarm_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` creates a shared mutex object, used for locking/unlocking.

`pthread_mutex_lock` locks the mutex as soon as it is available. It becomes unavailable for all other threads after this line is executed.
`pthread_mutex_unlock` unlocks the mutex, making it available again for other threads (unlocks the `pthread_mutex_lock` of another thread)

Comment: so when you do pthread_mutex_lock(&thread), does the thread start running from there? or does it start from pthread_create()

Comment: From pthread_create(). pthread_mutex_lock(&thread) will make it pause until another thread calls " unlock"

Comment: so would it be correct to say, from the code lock mutex to the unlocking of mutex, all the data there is being processed there cannot be interfered with?

Comment: Exactly. That's the point of mutexes : Between lock and unlock, only one thread at a time.

Comment: @Neozaru - note carefully what was asked there;)  Another thread will be unable to acquire the mutex, but the DATA is there and can be mutated - the mutating thread merely needs to avoid waiting for the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The mutex doesn't know what it is protecting. It is the programmer's job to know that and only change the data that it is protecting while the mutex is locked.

In this specific case it seems that the `alarm` list is the data being locked.